# .htaccess not loading up on CentOS

Tags: centos, .htaccess

For some reason none of my .htaccess files are loading.  What are the common things that make this happen?  I can use  in httpd.conf, and create it there, but it doesn't read .htaccess files in my directories.

Comment: Is that Apache server you are using?

Answer (score 2):

Ensure your `httpd.conf` has this line

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

If it does, are you on a Windows system? If so, you can't create but can update a file without a filename (i.e. `.htaccess`, `.bat` etc) - when running Windows, I rename my `.htaccess` to `htaccess` and update `httpd.conf` to read

```
AccessFileName htaccess
```

If you are getting an internal server error, check your apache logs as defined in the `ErrorLog` directive i.e.:

```
ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
```

and post that error here for further debugging.

Comment: How come you cannot update a file like ".htaccess" on Windows? I always can.

Comment: My mistake, Windows won't allow `.htaccess` creation, but will allow updating.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use AllowOverride to have Apache allow .htaccess directives.

Comment: when I do that I get an internal server error

Comment: You will find the reason for the "Internal Server Error" in your error.log.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lighttpd you CAN NOT use htaccess. You can put your htaccess settings only into lighttpd config file.